# Visual Studio doesn't recognise a project on the Mac

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

When I open a .NET project in Visual Studio on the Mac I see the following error:

[image]

This contains a `.sqlproj` file and a folder containing a SQL file. How do I resolve this? Is it a case that my Mac doesn't recognise a SQL project?

Comment: What is the sql file?

Comment: Database projects aren't supported in Visual Studio for Mac. There are no plans to support them that I know of. You'll have to use the latest version of Azure Data Studio

Comment: The SQL script creates a table, adds some data to the table, runs a stored procedure then clears everything down.

Comment: To back up @PanagiotisKanavos 's claim: [VS Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/624196/view.html)

Comment: That and many other Community requests are answered with the same canned response (whose expiry date passed a century ago) and closed out of hand. Somewhat understandable if you remember that VS for Mac is essentially Xamarin Studio and no mobile phone runs SQL Server. It's a lot harder to justify now that ADS does support database projects though.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I installed this on Windows instead. The IDE is much more suited to my needs.

Comment: Or you could use Azure Data Studio.